# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=1484, uid=10151, (need uid=1000)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am getting this error specifically on **HTC DESIRE 626GPLUS DUAL SIM** with Android **4.4.2**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=1484, uid=10151, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
       at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelAllNotifications(INotificationManager.java:271)
       at android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll(NotificationManager.java:220)
       at com.bakar.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:92)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Isn't UID 1000 a superuser? (same as sudo?)

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for that, I have same problem, try catch will prevent the crash but I think is not the best solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a `try-catch` to your code, like this :

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
try {
    nMgr.cancelAll();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

as `cancelAll()` may not be supported by the device model you mentioned.

Comment: this prevents the crash but isn't a solution I feel.

Answer (score 0):

You cant request userid 1000 as this is system userid

Comment: i am not requesting uid 1000 still this exception is occurring.

Comment: I am getting this error in these lines. `NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nMgr.cancelAll();`

Comment: as you can see exception also mentioned this error : `at android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll(NotificationManager.java:220)`