# Why NotificationManagerCompat::cancelAll() gets SecurityException?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-securityexception, android-binder

Using `NotificationManagerCompat` to cancel all notification.

```
NotificationManagerCompat manager =  
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx.getApplicationContext());
manager.cancelAll();
```

It got exception some time (most time works).

on Andoid 6:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=22994, uid=10184 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=22994, uid=10184 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1555)
   at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelAllNotifications(INotificationManager.java:649)
   at android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll(NotificationManager.java:323)
   at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.cancelAll(NotificationManagerCompat.java:197)
```

on Android 5.0, 4.4.2:

> ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=5460, uid=10135, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=3109, uid=10153, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
   at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.cancelAllNotifications(INotificationManager.java:271)
   at android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll(NotificationManager.java:220)
   at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.cancelAll(NotificationManagerCompat.java:197)
```

Questions:

1. What could be the cause?
2. What are those id here? Is it `ctx.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().uid` or `android.os.Process.myUid()`?

Comment: "is it ctx.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().uid or android.os.Process.myUid()?" -- for most Android apps, those should be the same. Both of your errors are rather strange, though.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! It is strange, it just uses the app's context to removeAll notifications (posted from inside the same app), but get security exception. What could be the possible cause?

Comment: @lannyf Irrespective of the exceptions, are your notifications getting cancelled or not ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari, no.

Comment: @Iannyg Did you find out solution?

Comment: Hey @lannyf did you found a solution? I got the same problem with my app occasionally throws this exception when notifications are calcelled.

Comment: @ Rybzor, no. seems this question is not popular enough.

Comment: So I guess gotta try-catch this cancer.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227027&thanks=227027&ts=1478202971

Comment: @66CLSjY I assume, depending on whether these `pid` and `uid` belong to your app OR not, this could be either a bug in "Binder synchronization" when, say, `getIntentSender()` was called with the `uid`'s `Binder` identity while it was to be called with the system's one (`uid`=1000), OR while handling your call other object's Binders are called with the original callers (yours) identity without clearing it first. I guess there isn't much you can do about it but catching exceptions thrown by the problem calls.

Comment: @Onik, that does shed some light on how this issue is arising. Thanks.

Comment: @Onik I don't want the bounty to go to waste. Pls summarize your comments as an answer, I will give it to you.

Comment: @66CLSjY I spent last weekend trying to figure out a possible cause and got nothing but the assumption which, by me, wasn't worth to post it as answer. So maybe it's fine to _"go to waste"_??? Sometimes we lose, sometimes we find :)... Yet if you insist, I'll gather all I've found and post the answer in hope it could be a good start for someone else in resolving the issue in future.

Comment: @Onik Pls do. Even though it does not contain a solution, it does offer an insight to the problem and address part one of the question asked by lannyf.

Comment: Can you post the manifest file and specify in which component you're trying to cancel the notifications?

Comment: Can you add your manifest? I think i met this issue before only on Asus phone

Comment: According to our Crashlytics reports, it happens only on Android 6.0 on Huawei P8 and Blackview P2. Three users, 10 crashes.

Answer (score 6):

*The answer **does not provide a solid solution** for the problem, it rather attempts to give an explanation of the cause both for the OP and [@66CLSjY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522448/66clsjy), who offered the bounty, with a [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227027&thanks=227027&ts=1478202971).*

---

**Inspecting the stacktrace**

According to the stacktrace `SecurityException` is thrown in the remote process: your app process' `Binder` object (e.g. `INotificationManager.Stub`, `ActivityManagerProxy` etc.) [makes a `Binder` transaction](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/app/INotificationManager.java#INotificationManager.Stub.Proxy.cancelAllNotifications%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) (`mRemote.transact()`) * on the remote `Binder` object and read from the object an exception (`_reply.readException()`) occurred within the remote call(s). If any, the [exception message is analyzed and a corresponding exception is thrown](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/os/Parcel.java#Parcel.readException%28int%2Cjava.lang.String%29) in your process.

**Analyzing the exception message**

Both the exception messages (one with [`getIntentSender()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService.getIntentSender%28int%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.os.IBinder%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Candroid.content.Intent%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cint%2Candroid.os.Bundle%2Cint%29) and another one with [`getCurrentUser()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService.getCurrentUser%28%29)) are quite straightforward - your app didn't pass a permission check, or in other words, the code snippets of `ActivityManagerService` that were supposed to be called [under the `system_server` process' identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005935/android-binder-clearing-caller-identity/40469633#40469633) (`UID=1000`) **, but, in fact, were called [under your app process' identity](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/rSbs4A27osk/a5BD4lHE9ksJ).

**Possible cause and workaround**

> It got exception some time (most time works).

Without making an assumption, what you get *"some time"* is improper `Android` behavior. [Wrapping the problem call with `try/catch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228896/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-getintentsender-from-pid-1484/32944378#32944378) seems to be a workaround until someone suggests a solid solution (if exists).

---

<sup>*  [ActivityManagerProxy.setRequestedOrientation()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java#ActivityManagerProxy.setRequestedOrientation%28android.os.IBinder%2Cint%29) and [IAccessibilityManager$Stub$Proxy.sendAccessibilityEvent()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/view/accessibility/IAccessibilityManager.java#IAccessibilityManager.Stub.Proxy.sendAccessibilityEvent%28android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent%2Cint%29)</sup> 

 <sup>** `android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS` is of [signature | system protection level](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser-apps.html#interacting_with_users)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like there are two different possibilities why this is not working:

The most likely cause is that you are using the wrong context to make the call; `getApplicationContext()` is not 100% reliable and sometimes produces strange errors, it is always best to avoid this call. If you are calling `cancelAll()` from a Service or Activity, use `YourClass.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`, if it is from a BroadcastReceiver, use the supplied Context variable.

If this is still not working, it might be a bug in `NotificationManagerCompat`, try if you can reproduce the same problem with `NotificationManager`. A workaround for that would be to save all your Notification ids in a list and then cancel them each with `manager.cancel(id)`. That way the system won't be trying to cancel any Notifications that do not belong to your app.